# MySQL replication uses unix_timestamp for timestamp type

Tags: mysql, replication, unix-timestamp

```
MySQL Version: 5.6.21-log
OS: CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
```

I have two MySQL servers with replicaiton.

Slave server get error **1032**

```
Could not execute Delete_rows event on table tosa.liv_low; Can't find record in 'liv_low', Error_code: 1032; handler error HA_ERR_END_OF_FILE; the event's master log mysql-bin.000005, end_log_pos 381675314
```

The sql query statement on mysqlbinlog is

```
DELETE FROM `tosa`.`liv_low`
WHERE
@1='BE41008-44500244'
@2=NULL
...
@30=NULL
@31=1418180543
@32=NULL
```

Original query is

```
DELETE FROM `tosa`.`liv_low` WHERE BOSA_ID = 'BE41008-44500244'
```

The 31st column on schema is

```
mysql> desc tosa.liv_low;

+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| BOSA_ID      | varchar(30) | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| LOT_NUM      | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
...
| TEC_current2 | float(5,2)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| IN_Date      | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| Human        | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

When I fetch a row, it has 'datetime' format value. And when I use timestamp value on WHERE clause, there is no result.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM `tosa`.`liv_low` WHERE BOSA_ID='BE41008-44500244'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
     BOSA_ID: BE41008-44500244
     LOT_NUM: NULL
  Kink_level: NULL
...
TEC_current2: NULL
     IN_Date: 2014-12-10 12:02:23
       Human: NULL
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-12-10 12:02:23')\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-12-10 12:02:23'): 1418180543
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM `tosa`.`liv_low` WHERE IN_Date = 1418180543\G
Empty set, 1 warning (0.18 sec)
```

Why does MySQL replication use 'unix_timestamp' format on timestamp type field? It brokes replication.

Here is a replication part of my.cnf:

```
server-id                 = 5202

replicate-ignore-db       = cacti

log-bin                   = /home/mysql/log/mysql-bin.log
binlog-format             = ROW
binlog_cache_size         = 2M
max_binlog_size           = 1G
expire_logs_days          = 40

sync_binlog               = 1

log-slave-updates         = true
gtid-mode                 = on
;disable-gtid-unsafe-statements = true
enforce-gtid-consistency  = true
master-info-repository    = TABLE
relay-log-info-repository = TABLE
sync-master-info          = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure this binlog comes from this SQL `DELETE FROM tosa.liv_low WHERE BOSA_ID = 'BE41008-44500244'`?

I did a simple test:

1. create table `create table a (id int(11), t timestamp)`(no primary key, at first I thought this might have something to do with a table without an explicit primary key)
2. insert data `insert into a (id) values (1)`
3. delete it `delete from a where id = 1`.

What's in binary log is still `delete from a where id = 1`

Tested on 5.6.21-70.1-log, binlog format is MIXED(should not matter anyway)

Comment: Thank you Dean. I tested same commands as you. The binary log has `DELETE FROM tosa.a WHERE @1=1 @2=1420678817`. I added my `my.cnf` into question.

Comment: Yes I can confirm that comes from `binlog_format=ROW`. If that can cause failure in replication, that seems a pretty serious bug to me. For you, the easy solution is to change `binlog_format` to `MIXED`

Comment: By the way, since your binlog format is ROW,what you see from the output of mysqlbinlog is not necessarily the SQL executed. And, is there a chance that someone or some code accidentally deleted that record on the slave already? I still can't believe MySQL would have such serious bug

Comment: No, because I skipped the position of the row that has error. And the row still remain on slave.

Comment: It seems not to related with timestmap. When I test on table 'a' more than 1000 times. It works very well. and My own errors also didn't occur every time. (It means most of same formatted queries worked well.)

Comment: I also think the simptons will go away if I change binlog_format from ROW to MIXED. But also curious why. Please tell me if I can try other.

Comment: Anyway, It solved after changed binlog_format = ROW to MIXED. The replication sync works fine. Thank you Dean. If there is something to try more, tell me please.

Comment: Well the binlog itself looks legit. Maybe try to look at the relay log. For more information, take a look at this: http://www.percona.com/blog/2010/05/06/debugging-problems-with-row-based-replication/